# How to fix lost connection to Access Database after Deploying ASP website to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am fairly new to ASP, so if anything doesn't make sense, or you think, "WHY WOULD YOU DO THAT?", it's becasue I really didn't know.

So the issue is that I created a Website using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.  It was an ASP.NET MVC.  I have spent over a week, working on this, doing testing and getting everything to work and look correctly.  So I started the process of deploying it.  I followed a couple guides, and felt like I did everything correctly.

Right now I am only trying to test my website on , and my first screen shows up.  This screen is a "login" screen of sorts and is supposed to connect to my Access Database to check to see if a user should be admited to the next screen.  But clicking the "Submit" button doesn't even open the Database.  All of this works fine when I run it in Visual Studio.

What can I do to get this working?

Some steps I have tried and failed at:
-Redeploying
-Changing location of the Access DB
-I started to try to install configure and convert my Access Database to SQL Server, but I haven't been able to get that to work either.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.  If you need code examples or IIS settings, I will get them to you as fast as I can, but please help me because I don't want to have lost over a week of work.

Thanks,
D

Edit: After taking the suggestion from **HansUp**, it lead me to some other search terms that lead me to http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/using-classic-asp-with-microsoft-access-databases-on-iis.  I am using a 64-bit machine, and my application pool in IIS was not set to run 32-bit applicaions which when using Access ODBC drivers that are 32-bit casue a problem.

Comment: Both the db file and the folder only had Read permissions.  I set them to Read and Write, and still no luck.

Comment: After doing some research for the IUSR account, I have also verified that Anonymous Authentication is Enabled for my Site in IIS.

Comment: HansUp, I can not answer my own question do to Rep limits for another 6 hours.  I will as soon as I can.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is this an ASP application, or an ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 1):

Set the IUSR account to Read/Write for the DB file and folder where the DB file is located.

Then, seeing as I was using a 64-bit machine, and the Access ODBC drivers that were being used were 32-bit, I had to set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to "true" in IIS, for the Application Pool that my site was using.

This is a link to where I found the 64-bit 32-bit solut 
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/using-classic-asp-with-microsoft-access-databases-on-iis